# I want to know the meaning behind asking these questions in this way

Tags: questions

Someone asked me these questions, even though we know each other for a little bit long time

**Who are you though? How did we ever find each other?**

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Can you add some more context?  (Where did you see these questions?  Who was asking them of whom?

Comment: thank you Adam,someone asked me these questions,even though we know each other for a little bit long time.

Comment: That does not help anything. I tried to answer you question with the best of my abilities, if it is wrong you need to update you quesion.

Comment: "Find each other" is sometimes (not always) related to the romantic notion that there is a "soulmate" or "perfect partner" out there in the world somewhere.  If you are lucky, you will "find **the one.** "  This may be a relationship question, more than an English language question.  If it is, I recommend asking the original speaker what they meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the question said "though" in it is because there is most likely something else going on :

ie, in a dialog between A & B:

> A: I came to save you.
>
> B: Who are you though? How did we ever find each other.

The *though* is making a transition between the previous statement (A saying *I came to save you* ) and the current one (B saying Who are you_ ).

Comment: Thank you Trevor Clarke, your answer is really helpful, I appreciate you.

Comment: thank you Adam and Trevor, but I'm still wondering that do the way of asking such questions mean I'm welcome or I am not welcome anymore.

Comment: Do you mean are you welcome to ask more questions? If so for sure, just try to add as much detail. and if you liked my answer please push that checkmark beside my answer, that would help me answer more questions!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: @Suade Actually, even when an answer seems to be a good one (I upvoted Trevor here) it is good practice to wait a little while to see what else comes down the pipe before accepting.  See http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer  If you found his answer helpful, you _should_ definitely check the upwards-pointing triangle to the left of his answer right away.  Then come back tomorrow and click on the check if his is still the most helpful answer here.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that, I am still new here, but really ELL is more than helpful.. thanks a lot